# Getting the maximum value from the group

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure as

```
Emp_id  Emp_name    Emp_sal Depat
1       AB          10000   A
2       CB          12000   A
3       DA          7000    B
4       SB          2000    B
5       WE          6000    A
6       CF          10000   B
7       AK          8000    C
8       LM          6000    C
```

I  need a  result as the maximum emp_sal  for each depart  group by depart 
Like

```
Emp_name   Emp_sal  Depart
CB         12000    A
CF         10000    B
AK         8000     C
```

I  wrote a query  as :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (emp_sal) , depart from emp 
group by depart
having emp_sal = (select max(emp_sal) from emp group by depart  )
```

But this did not work. I tried with several other queries but did not get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question as stated:

```
select max(emp_sal), depart
from emp 
group by depart
```

However, I suspect you want the *whole* row with the max salary for each department:

```
select emp_name, emp_sal, depart
from (select * from emp order by emp_sal desc) x
group by depart
```

Note: this is a mysql-only solution (with the whacky group by) but the question is tagged mysql and this works :)

Answer (score 0):

Max salary by department:

```
SELECT Depart, MAX(Emp_Sal)
  FROM emp
  GROUP BY Depart
```

List of employees who have the maximum salary in their department:

```
SELECT Depart, Emp_Name, Emp_Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE (Depart, Emp_Sal) IN (
  SELECT Depart, Max(Emp_Sal)
  FROM Emp
  GROUP BY Depart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Query if Emp_sal is unique for group:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c19e/10)**

```
SELECT 
t1.Emp_name,
t1.emp_sal,
t1.Depat 
FROM emp t1
WHERE  t1.emp_sal = (SELECT max(t2.emp_sal) 
                    FROM emp t2 
                    WHERE t2.Depat = t1.Depat)
```

If not unique for each group:

```
SELECT 
t1.Emp_name,
t1.emp_sal,
t1.Depat 
FROM emp t1
WHERE  t1.Emp_id = (SELECT t2.Emp_id 
                    FROM emp t2 
                    WHERE t2.Depat = t1.Depat
                    ORDER BY t2.Emp_sal DESC
                    LIMIT 1)
```

Result:

```
| EMP_NAME | EMP_SAL | DEPAT |
------------------------------
|       CB |   12000 |     A |
|       CF |   10000 |     B |
|       AK |    8000 |     C |
```